# bash substring weirdness

Tags: bash, substring

Here is a fragment of a password generator:

```
# ...
ascstring='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHILKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!#$%&()*+-;   <=>?@^_`{|}~'
asclen=${#ascstring} # modulo ascstring
#...
r=$(openssl rand 100000 | sha1sum) # generates 40 hex sequence
#...
for i in {0..38..2}
do
    v=${r:i:2} ; echo -n ${ascstring:$[ 0x$v % $asclen]:1}
done
echo
# ...
```

It uses various definitions of `ascstring` but the one shown causes a problem occasionally. 
Mostly it's okay:

```
$ ./password-gen.sh 
`?OCw&a|746|SRm8b&c=

$ ./password-gen.sh 
eE?R%3NdUjSpd<)wPuBV

$ ./password-gen.sh 
0X8)p8hPobt$x@iGy?!I

$ ./password-gen.sh 
P7LD;p<^lX1d87;{V4S$
```

But occasionally:

```
$ ./password-gen.sh 
5w@$ypassword-gen.sh@)A|l`06B(50f7
```

If I remove the `*` from `ascstring` this never seems to happen.
I wonder what's going on and how I can get around this problem (without reducing the entropy)?

Thanks.

Comment: Silly question perhaps, but what happens if instead of removing `*` you move it to first position in the ascstring (or last)?

Comment: That is due to [`globbing`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html), the character [*](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#ASTERISKREF) is expanded to list the contents of directory. You can disable using `set -f`, so maybe one option might be using `set -f` before setting value of `ascstring`

Comment: `$[..]` is deprecated; use `$((..))` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should quote the string to echo:

```
...
echo -n "${ascstring:$[ 0x$v % $asclen]:1}"
```